# VS2017 MFC Class Wizard - how to use it like in VS2015

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2017

Please tell me how to use new class wizard in VS2017.
In 2015 I could doublecliked and I got wizard to create class (base f.e. on CDialogEX).
VS generated code with enum, declare_dynamics and others things to connect with dialog.

In 2017 it create simple class only with constructor.

Comment: Did you create an MFC project?

Comment: I edit existing project.

Answer (score 0):

Everything ok. I had to modify installation program and add MFC + ALT. I thought that it was installed, because during installation I clicked that I want to use c++.